# Merge multiple regex, how can I know which part got matched?

Tags: perl

Here's a minimal case,

I have multiple regex, that is `aa`, `bb`, and `cc`, in the old days, I just loop through all regex and see if the string can match any of those. If any regex got matched, stop the process.

But now I decided to put it altogether, with a simple OR operation, now I get

`(aa)|(bb)|(cc)`

So if I get a match, the `$1` would be what I wanted, but I wouldn't be able to know if it's `(aa)` or `(bb)` or `(cc)` that did it, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, if aa matched, `$1` will be set; if bb matched, `$1` will be undef and `$2` will be set, etc.

```
if ( defined $1 ) {
    print "first part matched: $1.\n";
}
elsif ( defined $2 ) {
    print "second part matched: $2.\n";
}
...
```

or, more dynamically, using `@-` and `@+`:

```
my $string = "xbb";
if ( $string =~ /(aa)|(bb)|(cc)/ ) {
    my $match = ( grep defined $-[$_], 1..$#- )[0];
    if ( defined $match ) {
        print "part $match matched: " . substr( $string, $-[$match], $+[$match]-$-[$match] ) . ".\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I get it, and do you think I can come to the first defined $X directly without a loop from $1 .. $N?

Comment: And no, I didn't want `(aa|bb|cc)` ;-P